# Anyone know why a mongodb replica set would have a primary and secondary swap in rather quick succession?

Tags: mongodb, replication, failover

We have 3 mongo servers set up as replicas, one of which cannot ever become the primary, (backup). Let's say mongo1 is primary and mongo[2..3] are secondaries. Randomly mongo1 will not be reachable by mongo2 and mongo3, which results in mongo2 being elected as primary. Mongo1 then sees this and becomes primary. Then mongo2 and 3 see mongo1 again after a few seconds or so and it gets re-elected.

Is there a reason why it would re-elect mongo1 so quickly? Both mongo 1 and 2 have the same priority.

The issue of this is that it disconnects the mongo routers from each of our webservers which takes a while to rediscover which is the primary and connect to it.

Also, should mongodb routers be on the application server or separate server? In the mongodb manual it suggests to put it on each application server but what are the benefits of doing it this way? What would be the benefits and issues with having router servers in between the application and mongo servers?

I should mention this is in AWS (ec2), if that makes a difference.

edit:

running mongo 2.4.6 as a -sharded- replica set. Sorry about that, I forgot to mention that portion. They are rather high load. The mongo instances are all in the same region and same availability zone in EC2.

Comment: By mongodb router do you mean a mongos process? Can you run rs.status() and rs.conf() and add the output to your question?

Comment: here's a pastebin of the rs.status and rs.conf http://pastebin.com/0Gij2Nkv

and yes, mongos process

Comment: Exact issue can be known by analysing logs. Is it a high load environment? Did you try resyncing secondaries ?

Comment: Are you running a replica set or a sharded cluster? In the replica set configuration there is no separate router component (a sharded cluster has `mongos` processes). Can you clarify what you are referring to as the "routers"? Can you also provide more detail on your replica set deployment: Are your MongoDB servers geographically distributed? What type of AWS instances are these? Also, what version of MongoDB?

Comment: added more information to original post

Answer (score 0):

1. Why should you put mongos on the same instance as your application server?
   Network hops / latency. Querying a local mongos for an authoritative shard is quicker than doing a remote query — both approaches will then need fetch the data from the right shard.
   On a side note: Other databases like Couchbase avoid the mongos / router component to avoid this overhead altogether.
2. I assume you have split your primary and secondaries across multiple availability zones? Maybe the network is a bit shaky, although it shouldn't be? Unfortunately, there's not much you can do against failovers if you have network split — not failing over quickly would open bigger rollback windows, which you'd want to avoid. Unless you want to disable automatic failover altogether.
   And a node should only get reelected, if the new primary loses its majority. So in your case it looks like 2 and 3 cannot connect to 2. So 2 becomes the new primary. But soon afterwards 1 and 3 cannot connect to 2, and since they have a majority, they elect 1 to the be the master again.